# Custom Google Maps Buttons Position

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to modify my google map in the following way:

[image]

so I would like to have 2 (or more) couples of buttons (with custom icon) on the bottom left of the map BUT on the top of the standard buttons of google that is streetview and zoom..
Do you think is possible?
So far i was only able to move my custom buttom on the BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM_RIGHT, BOTTOM and so on..
Also as you can see I would like to have a VERTICAL Drawing Manager and not a horizontal one.

This is what I did: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cristinanardin/cdb68/52/)

In particular when I do this

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM].push(customControlDiv);
```

i would like to add instead some coordinate or pixel positions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define coordinates or pixel positions, but you may control the position via CSS.

e.g. for controls placed at the BOTTOM use `margin-bottom` to move them upwards from the position that has been set by the API

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    },
    noClear: true,
    disableDefaultUI:true
  });
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('ctrl1'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('ctrl2'));

}
```

```css
html,
      body,
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #ctrls {
        display: none;
      }
      #ctrl1 {
        margin: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        background: red;
      }
      #ctrl1::before {
        content: '#ctrl1';
        display: block;
      }
      #ctrl2 {
        margin: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        background: yellow;
      }
      #ctrl2::before {
        content: '#ctrl2';
        display: block;
      }
      .ctrl {
        border: 1px solid #818181;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      .ctrl strong{
        border: 1px solid #818181;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background:#fff;
        display:block;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map">
  <div id="ctrls">
    <div id="ctrl1" class="ctrl">
      <strong>Button 1-1</strong>
      <strong>Button 1-2</strong>
    </div>
    <div id="ctrl2" class="ctrl">
      <strong>Button 2-1</strong>
      <strong>Button 2-2</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```